# Negative integer division surprising result

Tags: python, division, integer-division

In my application I encountered the following and was surprised by the results:

`8/-7=-2` (both integers).

What does this mean?

Comment: In Python 2 only? In Python 3.8.10 (approx. 2021-11-26), the result on the screen is `-1.1428571428571428`.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

For the actual values, i.e. `8.0/(-7.0)`, the result is roughly `-1.143`.

Your result using integer division is being rounded down toward the more negative value of `-2`. (This is also known as "Floor division")

This is why you will get the somewhat perplexing answers of:

```
>>> 8/(-7)
-2
>>> 8/7
1
```

**Note:** This is "fixed" in Python 3, where the result of `8/(-7)` would be `-1.143`. So if you have no reason to be using Python 2, you should upgrade. ;)

In Python 3, if you still want integer division, you can use the `//` operator. This will give you the same answer as `8/(-7)` would in Python 2.

Here's a Python Enhancement Proposal on the subject: [PEP 238 -- Changing the Division Operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/)

Comment: @Ira: Yup! They changed this for python 3 though.

Comment: It seems like it should round towards zero if it's going to round.

Comment: @intuited: Well, seems like, perhaps, but that's only if you don't think like a computer. 5/2 is the same thing as a one bit right shift, you get 2 in both cases. -5/2 should then be the same as a right shift of -5, and that's -3. The problem here is of course that Python is a high level language, and you shouldn't have to know this. Which is why integer division was wrongin the first place, which has now been fixed.

Comment: @Lennart: so you divide -5 by 2 and get -3 with a remainder of 1.  "To settle our 5 emu debt to you, we will each pay you 3 emus, and you will provide us with one emu to wing us both home godspeed".  Sure, makes sense I guess.

Comment: @intuited: Ah well, yes, the *remainder* I agree is quite a surprise. :-)

Comment: @intuited:  a should equal (a//b)*b + a%b.  Thus -5//2 == -3.

Comment: @Neil: I would have expected that `-5 // 2 == -2` and `-5 % 2 == -1`.  In other words, we still owe you an emu for next time.

Comment: @intuited: that makes sense, but don't you want `-5 % 2 == 5 % 2` since they're in the same equivalence class?

Comment: @LennartRegebro: For all x and y within the realm of natural numbers or real numbers, using the division operator defined for the realm, (n+d)/d = (n/d)+1.  Python defines integer division in such a way that that useful axiom holds even when n is negative.  Even if some people might expect that integers should borrow the (-n)/d = -(n/d) from real numbers, that axiom is very seldom useful.  When trying to extract digits from a number, having "-123 mod 10" yield 7 isn't terribly useful, but having it yield -3 is no better.

Comment: @intuited I think that's just how it works in maths (modulo arithmetic). Programming languages are mostly just respecting this definition.

Comment: Quick question, how would I make say -3//4 return 0 and not -1 in Python 3? I do not want it to round down when negative. Essentially I want to  do this - "division should truncate toward zero."

Answer (score 26):

Python always does the "floor division" for both negative numbers division and positive numbers division.

That is

```
1/10 = 0
1/-10 = -1
```

But sometime we need 1/-10 to be 0

I figure out it can be done by using the float division first then cast result to int, e.g.

```
int(float(1)/-10) = 0
```

That works fine for me, no need to import the future division or upgrade to Python 3

Hope it can help you~

Answer (score 8):

To have Python automatically convert integer division to float, you can use:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Now:

```
8/-7=-1.1428571428571428
```

This feature is not in the standard Python 2 not to break existing code that relied on integer division.

However, this is the default behavior for Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

When both values are integers when dividing Python uses Floor division.

Comment: But only for Python 2? Perhaps [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5535242/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Answer (score -1):

In Python, `/` operator is for integer division. You can look at it as float division followed by a `floor` operation.

For example,

> 8/7 == floor(8.0/7.0) == 1
>
> 8/-7 == floor(8.0/-7.0) == -2

Comment: No, / is not for integer division, it's for division. However, in Python 2 dividing two integers would return an integer. This is surprising and has been fixed in Python 3.

Comment: @Lennart: Not exactly a shock for C programmers, nor for anyone who'd read the manual, and not "wrong".

Comment: @John: It violates core principles of Python and hence can be called "wrong" in the context of Python.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 No, it's *unexpected* for a C/C++ programmer that does not know Python. It is however not "wrong" for them either.

Comment: But only for Python 2? Perhaps [update your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5535261/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)?