# why python int() works like this?

Tags: python, int

Just randomly tried out this:

```
>>> int(-1/2)
-1
>>> int(-0.5)
0
```

why the results are different??

Comment: Do `from __future__ import division` before that and you'll get the result you expect ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> -1/2
-1
>>> -0.5
-0.5
```

The difference is that integer division (the former) results in an integer in some versions of Python, instead of a float like the second number is. You're using `int` on two different numbers, so you'll get different results. If you specify floats first, you'll see the difference disappear.

```
>>> -1.0/2.0
-0.5
>>> int(-1.0/2.0)
0
>>> int(-0.5)
0
```

Comment: Some == Python 2.x by default.

Answer (score 2):

The difference you see is due to how rounding works in Python. The `int()` function [truncates to zero](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), as noted in the docs:

> If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.

On the other hand, when both operands are integers, the `/` acts as though a [mathematical floor operation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) was applied:

> Plain or long integer division yields an integer of the same type; the result is that of mathematical division with the ‘floor’ function applied to the result.

So, in your first case, `-1 / 2` results, theoretically, in `-0.5`, but because both operands are ints, Python essentially floors the result, which makes it `-1`. `int(-1)` is `-1`, of course. In your second example, `int` is applied directly to `-0.5`, a float, and so `int` truncates towards 0, resulting in `0`.

(This is true of Python 2.x, which I suspect you are using.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of two things:

- Python 2.x does integer division when you divide two integers;
- Python uses "Floored" division for negative numbers.

[Negative integer division surprising result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/python-negative-integer-division-surprising-result)

http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html

Force at least one number to float, and the results will no longer surprise you.

```
assert int(-1.0/2) == 0
```

As others have noted, in Python 3.x the default for division of integers is to promote the result to float if there would be a nonzero remainder from the division.

Answer (score 1):

As TheSoundDefense mentioned, it depends upon the version. In Python 3.3.2:

```
>>> int(-1/2)
0
>>> int(-0.5)
0
```

Answer (score 1):

int() command truncates towards 0, unlike floor() which rounds downwards to the next integer. 
So int(-0.5) is clearly 0.

As for -1/2, actually -1/2 is equal to -1! Therefore rounding downwards to the next integer is -1. In Python 2, -a/b != -(a/b). Actually, -1/2 equals floor(-1.0 / 2.0), which is -1.