# Python 2.7.10 inbuilt calculation trouble

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can you explain what's happening with python shell..

```
>>> 6/7   
0

>>> -6/7   
-1

>>> -(6/7)    
0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Negative integer division surprising result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/negative-integer-division-surprising-result)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python

Answer (score 1):

With the `/` operator python always rounds to minus infinity (so to the "more negative" value) if you input integers, like stated in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). This explains the described behavior.

So `6/7` would be `0.857...` and gets rounded to `0` while `-6/7` gives `-0.857...` and will be rounded to `-1`. Finally `-0` equals `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform floating point division you should set the following import at the top of your script or as the first line in your Python shell:

```
from __future__ import division
```

This will ensure that you get proper results. If you want to perform integer division use `//` instead.