# Why does Python return the value '-0.0'?

Tags: python, python-3.5, division, zero, negative-number

An example:

```
> dhcp-wifi-8021x-155-41-14-238:~ user$ python
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 16:30:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 0/-1
-0.0
```

Why does Python return -0.0 instead of 0.0?

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535239/3780625

Comment: @Maxouille OP is using Python 3.

Comment: This post is just to explain that this is the normal behavior of division. `0` or `-0` are the same. Division works like multiplication: - / - and + / + returns a positive value while - / + and + / - returns a negative number.

Comment: You make it look like there's something weird with the minus-sign, but in fact `6/2` also gives `3.0`, and `8/4` gives `2.0`, so you seem to get a floating point number at every division.

Comment: You can also check this using the `type()` function : `type(6)` gives `<class 'int'>`, while `type(6/3)` gives `<class 'float'>`. If you really need the integer division, you need to put double slashes, as you can see here: `6//2` gives `3`, `type(6//2)` gives `<class 'int'>`.