# python negative number divide the number than itself the result is always -1

Tags: python-3.x

i have a question about division of negative number in python3

when I do the calculation for 6//(-132) why it is -1 intead of 0 .

what is the mechanism that python deal with this division?

Comment: You're doing an integer division, the result is always floor of its decimal version. Since all your division are between 0 and -1 you always get -1

Comment: oh i see , i got it now, thank u guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the remainder operation the python always takes the floor or the greatest integer function as the answer

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you're not using Python 3.x, you're using Python 2.x and what you see is the result of integer division, which was the default back then:

```
>>> 1/(-2) 
-1
>>> -1/2
-1
>>> -23/45
-1
```

To get the expected results in Python 2.x, try this:

```
from __future__ import division

>>> 1/(-2) 
-0.5
>>> -1/2
-0.5
>>> -23/45
-0.5111111111111111
```

Now, for the question **after the edit**: When you do integer division `//` the value will be rounded down toward the negative value of -1. (this is also known as "floor division"). See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5535206/201359) for further details.

```
>>> 6 / (-132)
-0.045454545454545456
>>> 6 // (-132)
-1
```

Comment: oh sorry yeah is python2, but for python3 why 6//(-132) is -1, I will edit my question

Comment: I edited my answer for the new question,

Answer (score 1):

Well most probably you are not using python 3 because in my idle python 3.8 on 1/-2 it shows -0.5 and the same in case of -1/2

Comment: oh sorry yeah is python2, but for python3 why 6//(-132) is -1, I will edit my question