# What is the rule behind minus (-) number devide by (//) integer division

Tags: python, python-3.x, floor-division

In Python, the principle behind integer division, which is denoted by two forward slashes `//`, is to divide one integer by another, and rather than giving the exact answer, it rounds down the answer to an integer. I can understand that part.

```
print(8//5)
# output : 1
```

But why does the output differ when the first number is negative?

```
print(-8//5)
# output : -2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/negative-integer-division-surprising-result

Comment: 1 is the nearest integer below 1.6, but -2 is the nearest integer below -1.6.

Comment: It is related to remainder(Modular Arithmetic) properties. In python `8/5` gives ` `1.6` and then it performs a floor operation. So 1.6 becomes 1. But in case of negative numbers, floor of -1.6 is -2. (Closest Integer Smaller than it)