# Same Python code returning different answer in Leetcode

Tags: python, algorithm, rpn

when I do Leetcode questions I write the code in PyCharm on my PC and when it's working I copy paste it into Leetcode.

This is the code I have written.

```
def main():
    # tokens = ["2", "1", "+", "3", "*"]
    # tokens = ["4", "13", "5", "/", "+"]
    tokens = ["10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+"]
    print(eval_rpn(tokens))


def eval_rpn(tokens):
    stack = []
    ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

    for c in tokens:
        if c not in ops:
            stack.append(c)
        else:
            num2 = int(stack.pop())
            num1 = int(stack.pop())

            if c == "+":
                total = num1 + num2
            elif c == "-":
                total = num1 - num2
            elif c == "*":
                total = num1 * num2
            else:  # The only operator left is division
                total = num1 / num2

            stack.append(total)

    return stack[-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the code I have pasted and submitted in Leetcode.

```
class Solution(object):
    def evalRPN(self, tokens):
        stack = []
        ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

        for c in tokens:
            if c not in ops:
                stack.append(c)
            else:
                num2 = int(stack.pop())
                num1 = int(stack.pop())

                if c == "+":
                    total = num1 + num2
                elif c == "-":
                    total = num1 - num2
                elif c == "*":
                    total = num1 * num2
                else:
                    total = num1 / num2

                stack.append(total)

        return stack[-1]
```

But for some reason for the input `tokens = ["10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+"]` Leetcode returns 12. When I run the same code on my PC it returns 22. 22 is the expected output. Not 12.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

[The Leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/)

Comment: Different python version? E.g. in python2 `/` is integer division when supplied with ints, but in python3 it will return float

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please copy-paste the assignment/exercise into your question, to make it self-contained. Linked pages can change, or disappear, making your question close to worthless.

Comment: One possible problem comes with `6 / -132` which is `−0,045454545`. If you're supposed to only deal with integers then that will not work.

Comment: Leetcode has never bothered to update to Python3.  They are teaching you a dead language.

Comment: @FrankYellin, that is not true. LeetCode has many language options, including Python 3.

Comment: @trincot.  My apologies then.  This is recent.  When a played around with it a couple of years ago it didn't.  And that was long after Python2's death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of different version(Python 2.7) you might have selected in leetcode editor

[image]

And this is happening because of the way how python 2.7 handles negative number division , if you follow your code you will see at one point the value in stack would be -132 and then the subsequent division with 6 is making the result as -1

```
print 6/-132 # results in -1
```

For detailed explanation see this [Negative integer division surprising result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535206/negative-integer-division-surprising-result)

This behaviour is handled in python3 and if you change your editor version to python3 it will work as expected.

Comment: Idk why your comment is downvoted. You explained it well and now i was able to make it work. All this time I have been using python 2 in the Leetcode editor it seems. I always selected python and never saw there was a python3 option right below it. Anyways now I switched to python3 and it works.